# NioServerSocketChannel.doReadMessages() creates a NioSocketChannel instance ignoring user ChannelOptions

Tags: netty

**NioServerSocketChannel.doReadMessages()** creates a NioSocketChannel instance ignoring user-defined ChannelOptions.

*ServerBootstrap* and *Bootstrap* classes create channels by calling *AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister()* method.
Methods like *Bootstrap.connect()* and *ServerBootstrap.bind()* call method *AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister() - AbstractBootstrap.init()* which ends up setting user-defined channel config options, e.g. custom ALLOCATOR.

Although that happens for client channel (*Bootstrap.connect()*) and server listening channel (*ServerBootstrap.bind()*), when a server accepts a connection method **NioServerSocketChannel.doReadMessages()** is triggered, and this method just creates a new *NioSocketChannel* without making any changes to it's Channel config. As a result, this new channel's options will be **always default**, and all user settings will be completely ignored.

That makes it impossible, for example, to set a custom buffer allocator, because in spite of the fact that *NioServerSocketChannel* itself will have the correct allocator set by *ServerBootstrap.initAndRegister()*, channels on server will be created using the faulty **NioServerSocketChannel.doReadMessages()** method, and will always have the default allocator attached.
That holds for any other *ChannelOption*. The entire options configuration of those channels will be always default, no matter what a user sets.

Comment: Have you tested [ServerBootstrap.childOption](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.html#childOption(io.netty.channel.ChannelOption,%20T))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much Ferrybig!

The problem was exactly that, to set custom allocator for ServerBootstrap the following is required:

```
ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
serverBootstrap.option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, alloc)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, alloc);
```